# Selenium Element not intractable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Weird case happening here. I am trying to insert some keys in a username and password input field. It was working just fine and suddenly it did stop.

Just to make thing clear for everyone. Once I click on login button, I get redirected to the login page where I have my username and password input fields. and their divs are as follow.

[image]

in my selenium code I target the username and password element by their name.

```
user = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
user.send_keys('Myusername')
user.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

But when I run my code I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
```

Any idea why is error occurring? Please if you need more info just let me know

EDIT:

The Wait it did work but only at the first try, if I run it a second time it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    usern = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('myusername')
  File "/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the full code I tried:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('myusername')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('mypassword')
```

and it throws the above error.

and this is the screenshot[image]

Comment: Have you switched to headless mode?

Comment: No I didn't. How can I do that? Sorry I am a total beginner. How come it was working before and suddenly just stopped? Thank you so much for your patience mate

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: Do you have some delay / wait before `user = driver.find_element_by_name('username')` ?

Comment: I have a time. Sleep(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `ExplicitWait` :

try this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys('your user name')
```

If this does not work then two things :

1. Launch your **browser in full screen**  : `driver.maximize_window()`
2. Use of **ActionsChain** :

`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`    `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))).send_keys('your user name').perform()`

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.get("<link>")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'Card__OTSigninButton-sc')]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormUsername"))).send_keys('user name')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input#signInFormPassword"))).send_keys('password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='visible-lg'] input[name='signInSubmitButton']"))).click()
```

**imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: The first part worked but only at the first try, I tried to run it a second time adding the code for password, and start failing. I updated my post with the full trace error

Comment: Can you share that code you have written for `password`  ?Also Can you attach a pic of login page ? I have given 2 more ways in the solution .. try it out and let me know

Comment: I tired both solution. and the one I updated in my post, is the one that worked at the first try but now is failing

Comment: Can I have the direct URL ?

Comment: by any chance I can send it to you in private?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233800/discussion-between-cruisepandey-and-nayden-van).

Comment: @NaydenVan : Use the updated 1 section code.. should work now

Comment: It works, you are a life saver. Thank you so so so so so so much.